# Redmine create issue with REST API

Tags: rest, redmine, redmine-api

I am trying to create an issue in Redmine (V 2.3.4) via RESTful. I've read the documentation and tried the example which didn't work (HTTP-Code: 404).

```
POST http://easyredmine.digitronic.com/issues.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<issue>
    <project_id>1</project_id>
    <subject>Example</subject>
    <priority_id>4</priority_id>
</issue>
```

Then I tried this and it worked:

```
POST http://easyredmine.digitronic.com/projects/isda/issues.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<issue>
    <project_id>1</project_id>
    <subject>Example</subject>
    <priority_id>4</priority_id>
</issue>
```

I am using the taskadapter Redmine API which sends requests in the first form.

Comment: Have you ever enabled the [API-style authentication](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Authentication)?

Answer (score 0):

You get 404 Not Found in the first case because the project (with ID = 1) the issue has to be added to does not exist. In the second case, value in the element project_id is ignored because you already specified project identifier in the URL.

Comment: Thank you for Reply. I have executed this request: GET http://easyredmine.digitronic.com/projects.xml and i have received a project with id 39. When I try to make the request with the ID 39 I get the Same error.

Comment: Try GET http://easyredmine.digitronic.com/projects/39/issues.xml if you get 404 or not. Also instead of project numerical ID you can use project string identifier. Finally look at the Redmine log file for any clue.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a content-type header or you will get a 404

Answer (score 0):

I use redmine rest api with ruby and the create method works for me.I use json instead of xml.My web service looks like this

```
id=-1
url = Configuration.redmine+"/issues.json"
uri = URI.parse(url)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
req.basic_auth(user, pass)
req["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

payload = {
    issue: {
        project_id:project_id,
        tracker_id:tracker_id,
        status_id:status_id,
        priority_id:priority_id,
        subject:subject,
        description:description,
        fixed_version_id:fixed_version_id,
        author_id:author_id,
    }
}
req.body = payload.to_json

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

response = http.request(req)
if response.code=="201"
  data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  id=data["issue"]["id"]
end

 return id
end
```

this is ruby code.Hope its help you